# Implement User Claims, Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a page and I want to allow only users with a certain claim (CanViewContract) to access it. The api controller works as expected but the blazor side cannot read that claim, and always gives me an unauthorized error.

I use this attribute at the top of the page:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "CanViewContract")]
```

This is my blazor programs.cs

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Assistant.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new 
 Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
 
 // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the 
server project
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory> 
().CreateClient("Assistant.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IInvitationClientService, InvitationClientService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpClientContractService, HttpClientContractService>();

builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
    
builder.Services.AddLanguageContainer(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
options.AddPolicy("CanViewContract", policy => policy.RequireClaim("ViewContract", 
"true")));

 builder.Services
.AddBlazorise(options =>
{
    options.Immediate = true;
})
.AddBootstrapProviders()
.AddFontAwesomeIcons();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

My server side program.cs

```
public static void AddAuthorizationAndAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CanViewContract", policy => policy.RequireClaim("ViewContract", "true"));
        });


        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Is the claim being sent to the browser?

Comment: @BrianParker No, I checked the user's claims.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a namespace project you can add an static class as the following

```
    public static class Permissions
    {
        public static class Constracts
        {
            public const string View = "Permissions.Contracts.View";
            public const string Edit = "Permissions.Contracts.Edit";
            public const string Sign = "Permissions.Contracts.Sign";
        }
    }
```

You can add an static class an add this static method:

```
private static void RegisterPermissionClaims(AuthorizationOptions options)
        {
            foreach (var prop in typeof(Permissions).GetNestedTypes().SelectMany(c => c.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)))
            {
                var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(null);
                if (propertyValue is not null)
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(propertyValue.ToString(), policy => policy.RequireClaim(ApplicationClaimTypes.Permission, propertyValue.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
```

To configure this claims add this on the program.cs

```
.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
                {
                    RegisterPermissionClaims(options);
                })
```

Then to allow view the desired page you should only add this:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Contracts.View)]
```

Additionally in your controllers can add this annotation:

```
[Authorize(Policy = Permissions.Contracts.View)]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<List<Contracts>> GetAll()
{
    your logic....
}
```

This will allow you to scale your claims.

Hope to hear this work for you.

Comment: It did not work. I believe the claims are not being send to the WASM with the token.

Comment: I added the server program.cs with my quetion

Comment: Yes, you should include all claims on token, are you using JWT?

Comment: Yes, I use this method
services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding the claims to the api authorization options

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
            {
               opt.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add(Permissions.Contracts.View);
                opt.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add(Permissions.Contracts.View);
            });
```